# Xamarin Telerik RadListview doesn't bind in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.ios, telerik

I have a fairly simple listview that display 3 columns that works perfectly fine for Android. When I run it in iOS the listview is there (I put a weird color background to verify it is visible), but it has no items.

```xml
<telerikDataControls:RadListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Locations" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLocationList}" 
                                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemTapped="Locations_ItemTapped" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <local:GrayRadioButton x:Name="rbtSelectedLocation" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" GroupName="grpLocation" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
            </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```

Is there some setting necessary for it to work in iOS?

Thanks.

I am updating with some screen shots.

Android:

[image: android]

iOS

[image: ios]

Comment: Like FreakyAli stated, you probably have the RadListView in a StackLayout parent, or the Grid.row it is in is set to Height=Auto. Carefully read my article here https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/troubleshooting/controls-are-not-appearing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have verified that all this is correct. The control is inside a grid assigned to a row that has a height definition of '*'. I also set it to a fixed value and it did not make a difference. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Also, it works fine for Android.

Comment: The screenshots w/troubleshooting BG color were helpful, it verifies the RLV container is there. What happens if you remove VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand? Also, simplify the template contents to just a Label (to temporarily eliminate the custom button)

Comment: If you're still stuck, open a Ticket so the dev team can help https://prgress.co/DevToolsSupport. Once solved, you can come back here and let the community know what went wrong.

Comment: I removed the custom control and VerticalOptions with the same result (although that reminded me I need to put the custom instructions for iOS too!). I will open a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is an issue of Telerik views not showing up the issue is always gonna be packages not being available in the native or forms project.

On the [RadListView's](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/listview/listview-getting-started) getting started screen you can find the DLL's that your project would need to have.

Make sure your portable project has the following DLL's:

```
Telerik.XamarinForms.Common.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.SkiSharp.dll
```

And your iOS project needs to have the following:

```
Telerik.Xamarin.iOS.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.Common.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives.dll
Telerik.XamarinForms.SkiSharp.dll
```

Also make sure you read this warning:

> WARNING: RadListView control provides UI virtualization, this feature requires the visual parent to provide vertical or horizontal space. To avoid breaking UI virtualization or gesture mechanisms, please follow these rules: Do not place the RadListView control inside a StackLayout
> Do not place the RadListVew inside a ScrollView
> Do not set the RadListVew to a Grid RowDefinition Height="Auto"
> For additional information and solutions for these layouts, please check the Controls are not Appearing article.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have verified that all this is correct. The control is inside a grid assigned to a row that has a height definition of '*'. I also set it to a fixed value and it did not make a difference. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you try placing it in a different layout? Or remove it from the Grid and see if that works for you?

Comment: I placed it on a page where it was the only control with the same result.

Comment: Did u check the dll thing?

Comment: Yes I did. All references are there.

Comment: Thanks you were right in a way. It was the reference but looking at the project it looks like the reference is correct because the names are the same.

Comment: Well I think then my answer was supposed to be marked correct in that case, but anyway good for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my iOS project was referencing the Portable binaries and not the iOS binaries. When I corrected the paths the items appeared in the listview.